# Entity Framework SaveChanges When Adding

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, entity-framework

If all I'm doing is adding new items to the DB, will SaveChanges() ever return less than the number that was added?

For example, if I add 5 new items, could it return a value of 3 in some error conditions?

Basically, I want to be sure that simply catching any exceptions is enough error checking. And if not, what is the best way to check which items failed to be added.

Here is an example (Assume some Person class that we user for our POCOs):

```
db = new Database();
db.People.Add(p1);
db.People.Add(p2);
db.People.Add(p3);
db.People.Add(p4);
db.People.Add(p5);
db.SaveChanges(); //Will this only return 0, 5, or throw an exception or can it return 3???
```

Comment: If you are using simple List<T> you wouldn't need to worry about items not being added without you noticing it, it will throw exception if it meets any errors. What data structure are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `DbContext.SaveChanges()` will throw an exception if any entities fail to insert.

The count returned will match the number of rows affected at the database level - so it will return less if the rows already exist and are not modified. If you're purely inserting new records, checking the count is sufficient.

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Comment: If it throws an exception, is it possible that some entities inserted? Maybe that is a crazy edge case...

Comment: No, the ones that would have succeeded will roll back (it does the entire operation in a transaction).

Comment: Claudio clarified this below (and so did you just now...)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about, if any of the elements can't be persisted, nothing will be persisted.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx)

> SaveChanges operates within a transaction. SaveChanges will roll back that transaction and throw an exception if any of the dirty ObjectStateEntry objects cannot be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on [database transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). "A database transaction, by definition, must be atomic, consistent, isolated and durable." What that means is that if an error occurs during the transaction ALL changes are rolled back. That's what atomic stands for...